# Understanding recursive rules in Prolog

Tags: recursion, prolog

I am starting Prolog, courtesy of [Seven Languages in Seven Weeks](https://pragprog.com/titles/btlang/seven-languages-in-seven-weeks/), and struggling a bit with understanding how Prolog is handling recursion.

Given the following code:

```
sum(0, []).
sum(Total, [Head|Tail]) :- sum(Sum,Tail), Total is Head + Sum.

% executed in the Prolog interpreter:
sum(X, [1,2,3])
X = 6
```

I understand what this code is doing, but I am a little hung up on how the Prolog is resolving the recursive calls of `sum`. Mainly, it is strange to me that there is no explicit "return" within `sum`.

My understanding is that something like this happens:

**A. The interpreter attempts to unify the rule sum(X, [1,2,3]) by calling sum:**

```
0 Sum(X, [1, 2, 3])
1 Sum(Y, [2,3] 
2 Sum(Z, [3])
3 Sum(0, []) % our recursive base
```

**B. Once we hit the base fact, it climbs back up the recursive "stack":**

```
3 Sum(0, []), Total = 0 % we start at our base fact
2 Sum(1, [3]), Total = 3
1 Sum(2, [2, 3]), Total = 5 
0 Sum(X, [1, 2, 3]) Total = 6 % sweet, sweet unification
```

Is my understanding of how this is functioning correct? Or is there a better way for my imperative mind to think about/express what is going on above?

Comment: Also.. Try running the 'trace.' predicate, before your main predicate, press enter to step through, and you can see it hitting the bottom of the recursion [], then unfold itself back out.

Comment: The fact that the predicate's recursive calls have to be "unwound" to obtain the total is significant.  A more efficient implementation can be done by introducing an "auxiliary argument" for the total, putting the recursive calls into tail-recursive "last call" form, and it is [a common optimization in Prolog implementations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) that avoids any "unwinding" of the stack in such cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yup, your thinking is correct. I'll reword slightly what you said just so that it's maybe a bit clearer.

The first thing to do to understand Prolog execution is to realize that Prolog is like a weak theorem prover. It will try to make your queries true. So, when you enter the query `?- sum(X, [1,2,3]).`, Prolog will do its best to make it true. In that case, as we'll see, it will require binding `X` to `6`, let's see how.

The only elements you gave Prolog to prove that `sum(X, [1, 2, 3])` is true are

```
sum(0, []).
```

and

```
sum(Total, [Head|Tail]) :- sum(Sum,Tail), Total is Head + Sum.
```

Obvisouly, Prolog can't do anything with the first clause, because it can't unify `[]` and `[1, 2, 3]`. So it tries to prove your query by using the second clause.

Then what happens is that it tries to prove `sum(Sum,Tail)` and `Total is Head + Sum` sequentially. Proving the first of those two options will induce the recursive call and ultimately it will be called with `Tail` = `[]`. At this point, Prolog will use the first clause you gave it and will deduce that `Sum` is therefore `0`. It will now have the elements to prove the second part (`Total is Head + Sum`) at the last step of the recursion. Then the recursion is worked back up to the initial predicate as you guessed.

Answer (score 1):

This is correct.  The role of an explicit "return" is played by the unique way of satisfying the sum of an empty list in the predicates that define `sum/2`.

You may convince yourself of this by executing the goal `sum(X,[ ])` at the interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding of how Prolog handles recursion is absolutely correct! You've accurately traced the steps of the recursive calls and how unification works to find the solution.
Let me make you clear with a few key points:

1. The interpreter starts by trying to unify the
   goal `sum(X, [1,2,3])` with the head of a rule. In this case, it
   matches the second rule `sum(Total, [Head|Tail])`.
2. Unification requires matching the second argument
   (`[1,2,3]`) with `[Head|Tail]`. This succeeds by binding `Head` to 1 and
   `Tail` to `[2,3]`. Now, the interpreter needs to satisfy the subgoals in
   the body of the rule:

   - `sum(Sum, Tail)`: This calls the `sum` predicate again with `Sum` and
     `Tail`.This creates a new recursive call.
   - `Total is Head + Sum`:This part is evaluated after the recursive call
     returns.
3. The interpreter continues recursively
   until it reaches the base case `sum(0, [])`. This fact succeeds
   immediately, unifying `Sum` with 0.
4. Now, backtracking starts. The interpreter
   substitutes `0` for `Sum` in the second subgoal (`Total is Head + Sum`). This
   becomes `Total is 1 + 0`, which unifies `Total` with 1.
5. The process continues back up the recursive calls.
   At each step, the bindings for `Sum` and `Total` are updated based on the
   previous call. Finally, the original goal `sum(X, [1,2,3])` is unified with
   `X = 6`.